# How to query 2 SQL tables & change data with 1 query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

i'm having difficulties on query 2 tables & change the data on those 2 tables.

Here's what i wanted to do.

Get Table B "Max Qty" - Table A ("Actual Qty" - "WIP Qty") = Table B "Topup Qty"

Then change "Signal" value into NULL or 1-4 legend base on  (("Actual Qty" - "WIP Qty") / "Max Qty") x 100%

### Legend

NULL = More than or equal to 60%

1 = Less than or equal to 60%

2 = Less than or equal to 50%

3 = Less than or equal to 30%

4 = Less than or equal to 0%

From this:

```
TABLE A
- Products        Actual Qty    WIP QTY
- Product A        5            0
- Product B        5            0
- Product C        733          72
- Product D        532          90
- Product E        510          360


TABLE B     
- MIN QTY   MAX QTY TOPUP QTY   SIGNAL
- 100       1000    NULL        NULL
- 329       857     NULL        NULL
- 393       1025    NULL        NULL
- 262       683     NULL        NULL
- 319       832     NULL        NULL
```

To become like this:

```
TABLE A
- Products        Actual Qty    WIP QTY
- Product A        5            0
- Product B        5            0
- Product C        733          72
- Product D        532          90
- Product E        510          360


TABLE B     
- MIN QTY   MAX QTY TOPUP QTY   SIGNAL
- 100       1000    995         4
- 329       857     852         4
- 393       1025    220         NULL
- 262       683     61          NULL
- 319       832     680         4
```

Comment: Please post whatever query you have written and where exactly are you facing a problem

Comment: How are the tables related. What would be an expected example output.

Comment: It's 2 table & i need the command to execute query table A "Actual Qty" - "WIP Qty" = (insert the result into Table B) "Topup Qty". Then by using (("Actual Qty" - "WIP Qty") / "Max Qty") x 100% outcome result change the Table B "Signal" into 1-4 Legend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that TableB has some relation to TableA

This will not be possible if there is no way to relate between them.

```
DECLARE @tableA TABLE(Products VARCHAR(50), Actual_Qty INT, WIP_Qty INT)
DECLARE @tableB TABLE(Products VARCHAR(50), Min_Qty INT, Max_Qty INT, Topup_Qty INT, Signal INT)


INSERT INTO @tableA VALUES 
('Product A',5, 0),
('Product B', 5, 0),
('Product C', 733 , 72),
('Product D', 532 , 90),
('Product E', 510 , 360)

INSERT INTO @tableB VALUES
('Product A',100, 1000,995, 4),
('Product B',329, 857 ,852, 4),
('Product C',393, 1025,220, NULL),
('Product D',262, 683 ,61 , NULL),
('Product E',319, 832 ,680, 4)


SELECT A.Products,A.Actual_Qty,A.WIP_Qty,A.Actual_Qty-A.WIP_Qty Topup,'>' [ ],B.Products,B.Min_Qty,B.Max_Qty,B.Topup_Qty,B.Signal, 'now calculate > ' [ ]
, CONVERT(MONEY,(A.Actual_Qty-A.WIP_Qty )*100)/B.Max_Qty SignalTest
, CASE 
    WHEN CONVERT(MONEY,(A.Actual_Qty-A.WIP_Qty )*100)/B.Max_Qty >= 60 THEN 1
    WHEN CONVERT(MONEY,(A.Actual_Qty-A.WIP_Qty )*100)/B.Max_Qty BETWEEN 50 AND 60 THEN 2
    WHEN CONVERT(MONEY,(A.Actual_Qty-A.WIP_Qty )*100)/B.Max_Qty BETWEEN 30 AND 50 THEN 3
    WHEN CONVERT(MONEY,(A.Actual_Qty-A.WIP_Qty )*100)/B.Max_Qty < 30 THEN 4 
    END Signal

FROM @tableA A
INNER JOIN @tableB B ON B.Products = A.Products

/*Here is the update but, you can switch the tables for your tables*/
UPDATE B
SET B.Signal = (SELECT CASE 
    WHEN CONVERT(MONEY,(A.Actual_Qty-A.WIP_Qty )*100)/B.Max_Qty >= 60 THEN 1
    WHEN CONVERT(MONEY,(A.Actual_Qty-A.WIP_Qty )*100)/B.Max_Qty BETWEEN 50 AND 60 THEN 2
    WHEN CONVERT(MONEY,(A.Actual_Qty-A.WIP_Qty )*100)/B.Max_Qty BETWEEN 30 AND 50 THEN 3
    WHEN CONVERT(MONEY,(A.Actual_Qty-A.WIP_Qty )*100)/B.Max_Qty < 30 THEN 4 
    END Signal)

FROM @tableA A
INNER JOIN @tableB B ON B.Products = A.Products

SELECT
*
FROM @tableB
```